# How to change permissions on a couchdb database with python

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python

I am trying to add a user in the "_security" document of a database with python-couchdb.
I am getting an error because the "_security" document doesn't have an "_id" attribute.

```
import couchdb
couch=couchdb.Server("http://admin:admin@localhost:5984")
couch["db"]["_security"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/couchdb/client.py", line 977, in __repr__
    return '<%s %r@%r %r>' % (type(self).__name__, self.id, self.rev,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/couchdb/client.py", line 987, in id
    return self['_id']
KeyError: '_id'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do it is

```
import couchdb
couch=couchdb.Server("http://admin:admin@localhost:5984")
db=couch["db"]
security_doc=db.resource.get_json("_security")[2]
db.resource.put("_security",{u'admins': {u'names': [u'admin1','admin2','admin3'], u'roles': []}, u'members': {u'names': [], u'roles': []}})
```